# Spring MVC how to handle Joda Data Types as JSON

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa, jackson, jodatime

I'm starting a new spring mvc project. I'm using JPA for my entities mapping.
I had an entity name Account with a dateTime field annotated as followed:

```
@Entity
public class Account implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date openinTime;
    ..........
}
```

and an entity Client with a Date field as followed

```
@Entity
public class Client {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date birthDate;
```

}

in my Spring-mvc controller, i find an account by id and return it as followed

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/find", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<?> findAccountById(@RequestParam("accountId") Long accountId) {
    Account accountFound = accountService.findById(accountId);
    ResponseEntity<Account> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<Account>(accountFound, HttpStatus.OK);
    return responseEntity;
}
```

but, when i saved an account object with date like "2016-12-07 12:00:00", and then, try to retrieve it, the date i'm getting on the client side is "1481108400000"

So i decide to use jodatime instead of java.util.Date (hoping that it will solve my problem)

I have configure in my spring-mvc xml dispatcher file the dateFormatter. this is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

<mvc:default-servlet-handler />

<!-- Login Interceptor -->
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/protected/**" />
        <bean class="softbank.ui.interceptor.LoginInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
    <!-- workaround to fix IE8 problem -->
    <bean id="webContentInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" />
        <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true" />
        <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true" />
        <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true" />
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>

<!-- i18n -->
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="WEB-INF/i18n" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="true" />
</bean>
<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.FixedLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>

<!-- View Handler -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="true" />
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="xml" value="text/xml" />
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            <entry key="html" value="text/html" />
            <entry key="less" value="text/html" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="viewResolvers">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="objectMapper"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean"
    p:indentOutput="true" p:simpleDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss">
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean"
    p:targetObject-ref="objectMapper" p:targetMethod="registerModule">
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.JodaModule" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter" />
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="objectMapper" />
        </bean>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter" />
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

but i'm still getting and error : The prefix "p" for attribute "p:indentOutput" associated with an element type "bean" is not bound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must declare the `p` XML namespace as `xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"` in your `<beans>` element:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    ... <other namespaces> ...
>
```

After that, the JodaModule for Jackson should automatically format your JodaTime types.

Comment: Thanks very much Adam

Comment: Sorry Adam but, i'm now facing a new problem with Date field during the http put request. i have modified my question body. please can you look it again?

Comment: @blaiso - I suggest you post it as a new question (only the part relevant to your current problem) and roll back this one to the original version. Otherwise my answer does not make sense any more.